# Edit Action in ASP.NET MVC Controller fails to update changes to Entity Framework entity

Tags: entity-framework

So I have a view bound to an entity (tblOutreachSpecialist).  When that view posts back to the server, it sends back an instance of that entity (again, the entity tblOutreachSpecialist) with the changes recorded.

I am having difficulty saving these changes successfully, however.

I have an entity context with scope over the whole controller.

`[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public RedirectToRouteResult eOS(DAL.tblOutreachSpecialist spec)
        {`

```
        int id = spec.OSID;            
        tblOutreachSpecialist specold = ent.tblOutreachSpecialists.Where(c => c.OSID == id).FirstOrDefault();            
        specold = spec;
        specold.FirstName = spec.FirstName;
        specold.LastName = spec.LastName;
        specold.AreaCode = spec.AreaCode;
        specold.PhoneNumber = spec.PhoneNumber;
        specold.PhoneExtension = spec.PhoneExtension;
        specold.WirelessNumber = spec.WirelessNumber;
        specold.Fax = spec.Fax;
        specold.TTY = spec.TTY;
        specold.Email = spec.Email;
        specold.Mobile = spec.Mobile;
        specold.EmployeeStartDate = spec.EmployeeStartDate;
        specold.OSTargetGroup = spec.OSTargetGroup;
        specold.Location = spec.Location;
        specold.Username = spec.Username;
        specold.Domain = spec.Domain;
        specold.DateStamp = spec.DateStamp;
        ent.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("gOses");
    }
```

I've tried simply equating the two (specold=spec;); that didn't work.  As a result, I tried mapping the properties explicitly.

When I call SaveChanges(), it does not persist the changes in anyway.

I've also tried creating a new context in this action, finding the entity again and saving the changes.  No luck again.

Why won't the Entity framework see this as a change and save it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try removing `specold = spec;`?

Answer (score 0):

So I reworked the code and discovered that IE 9 was not sending a request back to the server (it's written using Ajax.ActionLink). So it was saving, but when I went to retrieve the same record, it was pulling the old values without going to the server and getting the updated record.